# How to ensure the remote-exec provisioner environment is the same as running ssh directly?

Tags: docker, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm able to run a command in my instance using ssh directly:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i myid_rsa centos@x.x.x.x sudo docker exec samdom samba-tool user create myuser Passw0rd
Warning: Permanently added 'x.x.x.x' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
User 'myuser' created successfully
```

I would like to do the same thing using a remote-exec provisioner:

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "centos"
      ...
    }
    inline = [
      ...
      "sudo docker exec samdom samba-tool user create myuser Passw0rd",
      ...
```

However, I get an error:

```
aws_instance.ad_server[0] (remote-exec): ERROR(<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>): Failed to add user 'myuser':  - unable to parse dn string
aws_instance.ad_server[0] (remote-exec):   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/user.py", line 197, in run
aws_instance.ad_server[0] (remote-exec):     gecos=gecos, loginshell=login_shell)
aws_instance.ad_server[0] (remote-exec):   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/samdb.py", line 356, in newuser
aws_instance.ad_server[0] (remote-exec):     dnsdomain = ldb.Dn(self, self.domain_dn()).canonical_str().replace("/", "")
```

I'm assuming its just that the environments are different for each approach, but I'm not sure how to correct this for the terraform provisioner.

Comment: I think the Terraform thing might be a bit of a red herring looking at some similar questions around samba-tool as it doesn't seem to handle errors very well. A lot of other questions point to a lack of an LDAP database and also to users not being created already in the Linux OS underneath (as they apparently need to map to there). I'm not sure what you have in the question right now is really answerable as it's not reproducible from what you've given. If you can rework this to be a [mcve] that reliably reproduces and is down to Terraform then that might be helpful.

Comment: I've figured out another way to add users, so happy to close this question if it isn't going to be helpful for other users.